# Opening SQL command from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I cannot find where the sqlcmd is? i just want the prompt. please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166559.aspx

To start the sqlcmd utility and connect to a default instance of SQL Server 
On the Start menu click Run. In the Open box type cmd, and then click OK to open a Command Prompt window.

At the command prompt, type sqlcmd.

Press ENTER.

You now have a trusted connection to the default instance of SQL Server that is running on your computer.

1> is the sqlcmd prompt that specifies the line number. Each time you press ENTER, the number increases by one.

To end the sqlcmd session, type EXIT at the sqlcmd prompt.

To start the sqlcmd utility and connect to a named instance of SQL Server 
Open a Command Prompt window, and type sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName. Replace myServer\instanceName with the name of the computer and the instance of SQL Server that you want to connect to.

Press ENTER.

The sqlcmd prompt (1>) indicates that you are connected to the specified instance of SQL Server.

Note:
Entered Transact-SQL statements are stored in a buffer. They are executed as a batch when the GO

**EDIT:**
Here's another page that helps with sqlcmd.exe

[SQL Server: A crash course in using SqlCmd to manage SQL Server Express](http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/EntryId/696/SQL-Server-A-crash-course-in-using-SqlCmd-to-manage-SQL-Server-Express.aspx)

Comment: dave its not working, it does start, but it shows me a blank screen and then after 10 seconds exists

Comment: On my workstation I only have SQL Server 2008 Express. When I just open sqlcmd, I too only get the command box and then it closes. When I use sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS, I get the >1 command prompt. I have a instance of SQL Server 2000 on the network that I can also connect to with sqlcmd -S MySQLServerName. I have updated my answer with another help link.